# TCPDF cómo guardar un pdf generado en una ruta de red

Tags: php, tcpdf

Estoy tratando de guardar en una ruta de mi red un documento pdf generado con la librería `TCPDF`, pero no lo he conseguido a pesar de que la carpeta tiene full permisos para **Everyone** y **Anonymous Logon**. (*en una carpeta local del servidor si se almacena el pdf de manera correcta*)

He intentado de esta manera:

```
$this->folder = '//servidor/carpeta/nombreArchivo.php';
$this->pdf = Output($this->folder, 'F');
```

Y obtengo este error:

> **Warning:** fopen(file:////servidor/carpeta/nombreArchivo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **...\TCPDF\include\tcpdf_static.php** on line **1821**

> **TCPDF ERROR:** Unable to create output file: //servidor/carpeta/nombreArchivo.php

Y de esta manera:

```
$this->folder = '\\\\servidor\\carpeta\\nombreArchivo.php';
$this->pdf = Output($this->folder, 'F');
```

Obteniendo el siguiente error:

> **Warning:** fopen(): remote host file access not supported, file://\servidor\carpeta\nombreArchivo.php in **...\TCPDF\include\tcpdf_static.php** on line **1821**

> **Warning:** fopen(file://\servidor\carpeta\nombreArchivo.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in **...\TCPDF\include\tcpdf_static.php** on line **1821**

> **TCPDF ERROR:** Unable to create output file: \servidor\carpeta\nombreArchivo.php

Alguna idea de lo que puede estar sucediendo que no me permite almacenar el archivo en esta ruta de red?

**PD:** Ya probé almacenar en una carpeta local el pdf y usar la función `copy` de `PHP` para copiar el archivo a la ruta de red, obteniendo un resultado similar:

> **Warning:** copy(//servidor/carpeta/nombreArchivo.php): failed to open stream: Permissions denied in **...\proyecto\Controllers\generarPdf.php** on line **37**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de investigar, opté por resolverlo con una conexión `FTP`.

De esta manera genero el archivo en el servidor local con `TCPDF` y posteriormente lo traslado al servidor remoto a través de las funciones `FTP` de `PHP`.

[Aquí encuentran](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.ftp.php) las diferentes funciones disponibles, aunque con las básicas debería ser suficiente.

En la [documentación oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ftp.examples-basic.php) exponen un ejemplo de uso básico.

```
<?php
    // establecer una conexión básica
    $conexion_ftp = ftp_connect($servidor_ftp); 
    
    // iniciar una sesión con nombre de usuario y contraseña
    $sesion_ftp = ftp_login($conexion_ftp, $usuario_ftp, $contrasena_ftp); 
    
    // verificar la conexión
    if ((!$conexion_ftp) || (!$sesion_ftp)) {  
        echo "¡La conexión FTP ha fallado!";
        echo "Se intentó conectar al $servidor_ftp por el usuario $usuario_ftp"; 
        exit; 
    } else {
        echo "Conexión a $servidor_ftp realizada con éxito, por el usuario $usuario_ftp";
    }
    
    // subir el archivo
    $carga_ftp = ftp_put($conexion_ftp, $archivo_destino, $archivo_origen, FTP_BINARY);  
    
    // comprobar el estado de la subida
    if (!$carga_ftp) {  
        echo "¡La subida FTP ha fallado!";
    } else {
        echo "Subida de $archivo_origen a $servidor_ftp como $archivo_destino";
    }
    
    // cerrar la conexión ftp 
    ftp_close($conexion_ftp);
?>
```

Espero que esta información le sirva de referencia a alguien que tenga un caso similar.